# Token based security for a web service

Tags: c#, web-services

I am coding a C# web service using web API 2 where some of the CRUD actions need to have some security based off of a user's subscription.

Each user has a unique string token as part of their subscription.

Before I write my code for the webservice security, can someone please inform me if the following is a safe and efficient technique, and if not, why this is not safe and efficient and some other ways to accomplish this task.

I am thinking as part of each webservice request, a string parameter with the user's token is included. This token is then used to ensure that the user making the request owns the object.

Here is an example of a current function with no security:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
[Route("Getdata/{id:int}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(Data))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetData(int id)
{
    Data data = await dbSetService.Get(id);
    if (data == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(data);
}
```

Here is an example of a function with the token based security:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
[Route("Getdata/{string:token},{id:int}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(Data))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetData(string token, int id)
{
    Data data = await dbSetService.Get(id);
    if (data == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    //Check if the owner of the data object has the correct token, and the object is returned if the token is correct
    return Ok(data);
}
```

The webservice can be accessed by anyone, from any application.

Answer (score 0):

The token itself is not the problem, but having the token in the GET as part of the querystring will make it readable for everybody in between the client and the server. Even if you use https. It's safer to add the token in the header of the http request (e.g. using the `Authorization` header); the head will also be encrypted using https (unlike the request). If you don't plan to use https, then it does not really matter, I guess.

Furthermore, I would add a filter class (and add is as property of the controller), so that you don't need to do the check in each method. But for a simple controller with 3 actions it may be overkill.